# How to make powershell wait for a batch file to complete the execution of all comand on remote-server

Tags: powershell, batch-file, start-process

```
$storesess = New-PSSession -ComputerName marshy -Credential marshy001
Enter-PSSession -Session $storesess
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {start-process C:\Users\marshmellow\Documents\Some\xyz.bat }
Exit-PSSession
```

Above is the script which calls a bat file saved on remote server C:\Users\marshmellow\Documents\Some\xyz.bat

The bat file has two commands one which sets the working directory using "pushd" and another which stops a application process. The second command takes a couple of minutes to complete. I have found that the `Start-Process` doesn't wait for the second command to complete successfully, it just fires the command and closes the process.

Is there any way to make the Start-Process wait for the command to get completed successfully as I have already tried using `-Wait`  which doesn't work.

If there's a way to even open a cmd session on the remote server and pass few commands in it saved in variables and that output is relayed to my PowerShell script even that is fine. can anyone please help?

Comment: What is your batch file question. I don't see one.

Comment: Hi Mark, The problem isn't with Batch file as when I double click and run, it runs fine but when triggered via the start-process it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Using cmd.exe might work?

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
    cmd /k  "C:\Users\marshmellow\Documents\Some\xyz.bat"
} -ErrorAction Stop
```

If not, you could probably `Start-Process -Wait` on cmd.exe, then supply the batch commands as an `-ArgumentList`

What do you get if you try this?

```
Invoke-Command -FilePath $PathToBatchFile
```

Comment: Invoke-Command thing gives access denied on the first command of bat file which sets working directory via pushd <path>. Can you be more clear when you say "supply the batch commands as an -ArgumentList"

Comment: ```Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
    cmd /k  "C:\Users\marshmellow\Documents\Some\xyz.bat"
} -ErrorAction Stop``` this when used by logging into the remote server manually it works but with PSSession it isn't working.

Comment: See my above edit - does it process correctly using that?

Comment: Hey, as said ```Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
    cmd /k  "C:\Users\marshmellow\Documents\Some\xyz.bat"
} -ErrorAction Stop ``` works absolutely fine if I log in to the server manually and use this command in PowerShell but it isn't working when I form a PSSession on the remote server. ``` Invoke-Command -FilePath $PathToBatchFile``` this doesn't work it's throwing up  below error

Comment: Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet. Just use `Start-Process` with the `-Wait` parameter and pass the correct parameters to cmd:

```bsh
$storesess = New-PSSession -ComputerName marshy -Credential marshy001
Enter-PSSession -Session $storesess
Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList "/C C:\Users\marshmellow\Documents\Some\xyz.bat" -Wait
Exit-PSSession
```

Comment: hey Thomas, your solution seems to be working the same way as mine here too the second command in bat file is being fired but it seems like the cmd session isn't waiting for the second command in bat to execute completely and the process is being closed.

Comment: @ShubhamMishra If I put `timeout /T 5` into the batch file twice, PowerShell waits 10 seconds until the process ends. So it seems to work as intended. What is inside you batch file? If you start threads from there, the batch script has to wait for them. PS cannot do that. Is there really a need for a batch file? Why not doing all the work in PS?

Comment: I tried this timeout /T 5 and it did make the bat to wait but it didn't resolve the issue. The bat file has two commands 1) Pushd <path> 2) calling a cmd file and passing a parameter to the cmd file to stop an application component. Recurring the point again the bat file doesn't have any issue as i have tested it manually. Is there a way to pass these two command via powershell?

Comment: as the second command stops an application component it takes time for the execution of the command. If the session is terminated then the component doesn't stop.

Comment: Like I said, if your batch script calls another batch script, then the calling batch script is responsible to wait for it. As it contains only the two calls, then do it in PS directly. Set your working directory with `Set-Location` and call the "secondary" batch script with the `Start-Process` cmdlet I put in my answer above.